# Aurelia doesn't work properly with Node-forge library

Tags: javascript, node.js, aurelia

I'm trying to use 'node-forge' for RSA-OAEPSHA1 encryption. Following command is used to add 'node-forge' to aulreia.json;

- $ au install node-forge

It's **downloaded successfully and updated aurelia.json** file too. But while we run the command 'au build', got a **file not found error**. Have attached the image here. How do I can sort out this?

[File not found - crypto js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y2pE.png)

Thanks!

Comment: While i'm not familiar with Aurelia the error seems obvious to me. "Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and **that it is not a Node.js package**". **node-forge** is a Node.js package so in other words you **can't use it with Aurelia**.

Comment: Thanks @Molda.. Have you any suggestions to get work with it? I'm a beginner for JS related stuff.

Comment: There's a library for browser https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#jsdelivr-cdn just read the documentation.